# Is Future Tense for If Conditional Necessary in Mathematical Context?

Tags: conditional-constructions

We use a future tense for a conditional sentence.

> If you rest, you will feel better.

> If you believe, you will receive whatever you ask for in prayer.

Must one follow this rule in mathematical contexts such as explaining `Y=2X`?

> *Y* will increase by 2 if *X* increases by 1.

> A number is in *B* if it is in *A.*

I am checking, in Wikipedia, [If and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) and [Conditional sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence) but seeing both present and future tenses together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mathematical context, the present tense or bare form is more natural. When X increases by 1, Y increases by 2.

Note that in your two examples of feeling better and getting free stuff through prayer, there is an actual futurity in your conditional statements. The improvements will follow the conditional actions after a time.

In the mathematical relations, everything is simultaneous.

If the Y=2X relationship applies to a physical system, especially one with a time lag, the future tense might make more sense, for example,
"If atmospheric CO2 doubles, the average global temperature will increase by 30C."

(I just made up those numbers, to make the point.)

Comment: So the actual simultaneity of the clauses matters in determining the tense. Thanks, but may I ask some more? Suppose the ```Y=2X``` again. How are the following sentences different?
A. Y increases by 2 if X increases by 1.
B. Y increases by 2 when X increases by 1.
C. Y increases by 2 as X increases by 1.
It seems mathematicians tend to use (1) A to express necessity and sufficiency (*e.g.,* *X* is an integer if *X* is a natural number.) and (2) C to express mathematical limits (*Y* converges to zero as *X* diverges to infinity.). I know B is correct but don't know when it is the best.

Comment: y=2x is a simple relationship. You can express it many ways, and it's needlessly elaborate to describe the relationship as a process, with increments.  Expression C with "as" doesn't fit. The use of "as" to express a limit fits because you need to invoke a process to accurately describe the relation.

Comment: Thanks, but the ```Y=2X``` is just an example—what if it is not a simple relationship? For example, a probability density function of the normal distribution.
Suppose I write "*f(x;μ,σ)* increases if/when *μ<x* increases but decreases if/when *σ* increases." Is the choice between if and that still needlessly elaborate?

Comment: That's a slightly different question than that of future tense, but if you check Google books for expressions about PDFs you will get a better idea of what the usage is. If usage is variable, it doesn't make any difference. I don't see any difference between if and when in that kind of expression, and future tense seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful answers to those bothering questions.